# Creating a loop within a method that keeps track of variable n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am trying to delete users and their emails from a database, and instead of completely removing the user, I have opted to soft delete the user, overwriting their username and email in case they want to sign up again in the future. Users cannot have duplicate emails, so I have to overwrite with a unique email each time.

The method to soft delete and overwrite Username and Email for accounts looks like this:

```
def soft_delete
  n = 1
  y = n + 1
  update_attribute(:name, ("DeletedUser"))
  update_attribute(:email, ("DeletedUserEmail"+(y.to_s)))
  update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
end
```

It works only for the first user that deletes their account. The second user gets the error that the email already exists.

I tried different ways of implementing this so that `y` keeps the count of the variable `n`, which increase as with users.

How would I go about this in the best way? I considered making a for loop. I also looked through [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), and came across:

```
(0..5).each do |i|
  puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

But not sure if it would be the best way to implement this function.

Comment: Why not just update_attribute(:email, ("DeletedUserEmail"+(id.to_s))) ?

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of :email, unless: :deleted_at` would only validate if the user's `deleted_at` attribute isn't set.

Comment: @leo I had not even considered that.. Thank you a lot. That quickly solved it and was a lot easier than the convoluted ways I considered

Comment: You don't have to put parentheses around strings – just write `"DeletedUser"` instead of `("DeletedUser")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a unique counter... the id of the record.

```
update_attribute(:email, ("DeletedUserEmail"+(id.to_s)))
```

Comment: Wow.. I hadn't considered that at all. Thank you, that solved it and made it waaay easier

Comment: You would typically use `"DeletedUserEmail#{id}"`

Comment: @stefan you are correct... I like to minimise refactoring changes in an OP's post that don't directly relate to the answer.  Either that, or I'm lazy. :)